# Patterns appearing in irrational approximation graphs

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, cauchy-sequences, approximation-theory

I'd like to know more about some patterns I found in graphs corresponding to irrational numbers. Here's the graph for $\sqrt 2$ for example
[[image: <span class=]$\sqrt 2$ log error graph" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb3QF.png)

First, I'll try to explain most naturally the function that generates this graph.

$\bullet\ \textbf{Explanation}$

Any irrational may be approximated as accurately as we wish by fractions. For example, here is a sequence of fractions that gets closer to $\sqrt{2}$

$$\frac{1}{1}\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}\rightarrow\frac{17}{12}\rightarrow\frac{577}{408}\rightarrow\ ...$$
This sequence is generated by applying Newton's method to $x^2-2=0$ (which, of course, is solved by $\sqrt{2}$). It's pretty accurate
$$\sqrt 2 = 1.41421{\bf356}$$
$$\frac{577}{408}=1.41421{\bf568}...$$
$408$ seems to be special because the best approximation with a denominator of $408$ has $5$ correct decimal places. However the best approximation with a denominator of $407$ only has $2$ correct decimal places!

$$\frac{576}{407}=1.41{\bf523}...$$

I tried to generalize this idea of a denominator being "more fitting" to some particular irrational number.

For some denominator $d$, we say that the error between the best fractional approximation with denominator $d$ - disregarding the possibility of simplifying the fraction - and an irrational number $r$. I.e.
$$\text{Error}_r(d):= \text{min}_n\big|\ \frac{n}{d}-r\ \big|$$
We now have

$$\text{# of correct digits} \approx -\text{log}(\text{Error}_r(d))$$
$$(\text{where "log" is base-}e)$$

A slight problem with this definition though is that bigger denominators inevitably all achieve smaller error than $408$.
So we will enforce a "penalty" for big denominators so that numbers like $408$ remain "special". I've been calling one such function "Log-Error"

$$\text{LogError}_r(d):=-\frac{\text{log}(\text{Error}_r(d))}{1+\text{log(d)}}$$

The graph above is merely a scatter plot of this function for $1 \le d < 1000$

Here are the graphs for $e$, $\pi$, and $(19-\sqrt{3})^{1/4}$:
[image: log error for e]
[image: log error for pi]
[image: log error for arbitrary algebraic number]

Oddly $\sqrt 2$ is the only irrational I've found that seems to have an increasing log-error function.

Any further info is appreciated. Specifically

> For which numbers irrational numbers does the log-error have a global maximum?
>
> Why do these patterns even appear in the first place?
>
> Does Newton's method always generate numerator minimizing the error?
>
> If so, are the fractions generated by Newton's method always local maxima of the log-error function?

Comment: The general phenomenon you're seeing is related to continued fraction expansions of irrational numbers; these "strangely good" denominators are (part of) the convergents of the continued fraction expansion.